# Python eve pagination requests along with update request

Tags: python, pagination, updates, eve

Python eve is so far looking very great for all use cases, except one where on a resource one client is paginating and during the same time some objects got updated, can we do sort of snapshot while pagination or any other way to handle the case?

Flow will be like

```
1. GET /foos 
2. GET /foos?page=2 
3. POST/PATCH /foos or /foos/ID (updates page1 or page 2 items)
4. GET /foos?page=3 (now it may contains items from page1/page2) unclear
```

Answer (score 1):

Eve simply returns the results from the underlying MongoDB driver, which is returning a [`Cursor`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) object itself. To my knowledge, the cursor does have a [`snapshot()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/) method which would do something similar to what you want to achieve. There are some relevant limitations however:

> The snapshot() does not guarantee isolation from insertion or deletions.

And:

> You can only use snapshot() with unsharded collections.

Eve does not support the snapshot method out of the box and, given the drawbacks (and the assumable performance hit) I do not think it should, not by deafult at least.

You could of course subclass the [default Mongo layer](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/io/mongo/mongo.py#L60) with your own implementation of the `find` method. By the way, I might consider a pull request, provided that this snapshot behaviour is configurable and defaults to inactive.

Comment: thanks, but for snapshot to works we need to store and keep open cursor and if client doesnot call the next page cursor should timeout? what do you think of this?